# AWS devicefarm testng execution queries

Tags: testng, aws-device-farm

I have simple queries and I am not able to figure out references to understand these. Can you please help me to understand these doubts?

- Does AWS DeviceFarm allows Test annotations? BeforeSuite, AfterSuite, Test, BeforeTest, AfterTest, groups, groupsOderBy, enabled.
- Does AWS DeviceFarm reads testing.xml file if we have place under root in the –test.jar?
- Does AWS DeviceFarm really runs only methods that mentioned in testing.xml file with include tag? I Don’t see it’s working. Irrespective of include methods mentioned, it is execuitng all methods annotated with test tag in the class file.
- Class Methods include and exclude tags really works in DeviceFarm?
- Let’s say If I have bunch of test classes and I want to run only few in the test execution. What is the exact way or best way to enable only few tests to run?
- Let’s say I have 5 tests and want to run it in sequential as a product limitation. What is the exact way or best way to run tests in sequential order?
- Why each class mentioned in test tag inside testing.xml is considered as separate test suite? Then in that case, what is the exact difference if I mentioned two three test suites in testng.xml file and each test suite is again having multiple test classes?
- Does suite name parallel="none" works in DeviceFarm?
  Appreciate if you can advise on these queries at the earliest and if you can provide direction for the exact documentation reference for further studies.
  Regards,
  Srinivas

Comment: Have you read through the documentation ? What happens when you try all these ? Where are you stuck ? What errors do you face ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

- Support:BeforeSuite, AfterSuite, Test, BeforeTest, AfterTest
- No support:  groups, groupsOderBy, enabled
  -

> Does AWS DeviceFarm reads testing.xml file if we have place under root
>   in the –test.jar?

- Yes

> Does AWS DeviceFarm really runs only methods that mentioned in
>   testing.xml file with include tag? I Don’t see it’s working.
>   Irrespective of include methods mentioned, it is execuitng all methods
>   annotated with test tag in the class file.

- No, it runs only class which has been include using  but it doesn´t understand

  > Class Methods include and exclude tags really works in DeviceFarm?
- No working

> Let’s say If I have bunch of test classes and I want to run only few
>   in the test execution. What is the exact way or best way to enable
>   only few tests to run?

- There are somes ways I tried:

  - You can put your test in several classes just like "TEST1.java, TEST2.java..."
  - In the pom.xml:

> ```
> <plugin>
>                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
>                     <version>2.6</version>
>                    <executions>
>                         <execution>
>                             <goals>
>                                 <goal>test-jar</goal>
>                             </goals>
>                         </execution>
>                     </executions>
>                       <configuration>
>                 <classifier>xxx</classifier>
>                 <includes>
>                   <include>**/*TestNameYouWantToRun*</include>
>                 </includes>
>               </configuration>
>                 </plugin>
> ```

In this way, you can include or exclude your test

If you don´t want to create so many classes and want to use several test methods, the only way works for me is comend the method you don´t want to run

Comment: Just a quick question, when I try to execute test cases using testng.xml, the sequence in which classes are mentioned is not followed while execution. Are you able to achieve desired sequencing? If yes, please help